# understanding intent-filter in android manifest.xml

Tags: android, intentfilter

In reading some android documentation, it seems like intent-filter indicates what intents the application is interested in. In my application, I am interested in receiving `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED`. I didn't declare it in my manfiest xml file, but in my application I register a `BroadcastReceiver` that filters on `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` and I receive the events just fine.

Can someone explain then why I would use intent-filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your application can receive the event even if it's not already running.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html:

Declares a broadcast receiver (a BroadcastReceiver subclass) as one of the application's components. Broadcast receivers enable applications to receive intents that are broadcast by the system or by other applications, even when other components of the application are not running.

There are two ways to make a broadcast receiver known to the system: One is declare it in the manifest file with this element. The other is to create the receiver dynamically in code and register it with the Context.registerReceiver() method. See the BroadcastReceiver class description for more on dynamically created receivers.

Comment: I see how that shows 2 ways to create a BroadcastReceiver, but how does that impact when/if intent-filter should be used in the application block of the manifest?

Comment: So that you can receive the event even if your service or application has previously been shutdown.  Android may terminate your app/service (e.g. if memory gets tight), or you may not want to keep your process running.

Comment: I see. In some of the example I've been reading, when an app declares an intent filter and the intent is performed elsewhere, the Android will propmpt the user to see which application they want to use to handle the intent.

Comment: Broadcast events should go to all registered receivers (wether set up in code or in the manifest).  You're not saying you can handle a certain intent, you're saying you want to be notified when a certain intent occurs.